# Prove that centering vectors reduces the span by 1 dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x_1, ..., x_m ∈ R^n$ be $m$ linearly independent $n$-dimensional vectors, and let $\mu$ be their mean. Prove that the centered points
$\bar{x_1} = x_1 - \mu, ...,\bar{x_m} = x_m - \mu$ span an $m-1$ dimensional subspace of $R^n$.

Up to this point I have managed to prove that the centered vectors are not linearly independent. I have been trying to prove that $m-1$ of these vectors are linearly independent using the definition of independence but without any result. Any tips?

Comment: A straightforward independence proof is definitely doable, but you can also more easily show that with the addition of one more vector, you'll span an $m$-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0):

You have the obvious linear relation 
$$\bar x_1+\dots+\bar x_m=0\iff x_1+\dots+x_m-m\mu=0$$
Suppose you have another, non-collinear, relation
 $$\lambda_1 \bar x_1+\dots+\lambda_m\bar x_m=0\iff \lambda_1 x_1+\dots+\lambda_m\ x_m-\Bigl(\sum_i\lambda_i\Bigr)\mu=0$$
You can eliminate $\mu$ from these relations if $\;\sum_i\lambda_1\ne 0$, obtaining a linear relation between the $x_i$s. If $\;\sum_i\lambda_1= 0$, you already have such a relation. n both cases, it contradicts the independence hypothesis. Thus the space of linear relations between the $\bar x_i$s has dimension $1$, which proves these vectors span a subspace of dimension $m-1$.